# Getting a segmentation fault when opening a file that already exists

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I was trying to open a file that already exists:

```
    program writeeven
    implicit none
    logical :: alive
    inquire(file='even.txt', exist=alive)
   if (alive) then
      print *, 'file is existed'
      open(12, file='even.txt')
   else
      print *, 'file is not existed'
   end if

   end program writeeven
```

The program gave the following message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
```

How can I open the existing file and read the message?

Comment: Can you give us the full error message, and maybe even the compiler that you used? I have tried your code with `gfortran 5.4` on Linux and it works just as expected.

Comment: I am using GNU Fortran Compiler that is in Code Blocks. The build message shows "Target is up to date; nothing to be done." . And when I run it, it always shows " Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
Backtrace for this error:" . Besides, if there is not file, it can be run successfully. I don't know how to solve this terrible problems. Thanks.

Comment: When the build message is: "Nothing to be done" then it hasn't done anything. The build system sounds like `make`, but I'm not sure. Delete the executable, the build it again, and post everything it outputs here.

Comment: Still the same result at the .exe! And besides, I find it cannot write a new message to cover this original one. I guess, the question is caused by the open comment which is seemly conflict with existed file.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it cannot wite ... to cover this original one"*?

Comment: I mean the first time I create a file to write some contents, the program is run successfully. But when I open it and write again, or directly open an exist file. It;'s failure. Of course, I try in another vs, using intel fortran compiler, it's OK.